# DocuSign Service Integration: Authorization Code human action

Tags: docusignapi

One of the steps to authorize our application to access our DocuSign account requires a human to navigate to the oauth service (https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=...) then login to the account, and grant it access.

I've seen some references throughout the developer portal about this being something that will need done multiple times, and I've also seen it written on the same site that it only needs to be done once (the site is actually fraught with contradicting information).

Does anyone know if this step will need to be done more than once? It makes sense to me that it should NOT.

Much appreciated!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html and it is a correct place for documentation for DocuSign. Now with above flow, you get two types of tokens i.e AccessToken and Refresh Token. If Access Token expires then you can use refresh token to get new set of access and refresh token and it does not need any consent from the user or a human action, it can be done using DocuSign OAUTH API from backend. But if the response to the refresh operation is an error, or if the new access token’s expires_in value is less than your threshold, you will need to repeat the initial authentication flow. So you need to do proper exception/error handling before taking user back to the consent/OAuth login page.

Comment: Thank you Amit. The user is not the account holder though. We have a standard contract that our customers sign, and they are the ones walking through the signing ceremony from a workflow on our website. So if the refresh operation is an error, or if we exceed the access token's expiration threshold, the user would be interrupted until someone from our IT dept or customer support can re-authorize the app to access our DocuSign account?

If so I must be doing something wrong. I am trying to follow the "service integration authentication" steps. Should I be looking at something else?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce a workflow similar to this one:
https://loancosample.docusign.com/loan/personal

Comment: If you are trying Service Integration, that means you are the owner of the envelopes and all envelopes will be sent from your account only. You will send envelopes to customer for signature but all envelopes will be sent from your DocuSign account, then you can use service integration as explained here, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/legacy_auth.html

Comment: Thanks again Amit! For clarity sake, I should be using "legacy header authentication", and not "service integration authentication" as it says at the top of that page?

Legacy header authentication is what all the examples use. I was hesitant to use the legacy stuff if another option is available.

Comment: Yes, legacy header authentication will be suffice for you.

Comment: While working on implementing legacy header authentication as the solution here describes, I ran into further problems and have posted another question about it. Linking to that question here to help anyone following along:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671918/docusign-legacy-header-authentication-error